# Copy Value from Worksheet "datastore" A1 to Worksheet "1" D4..."datastore" A2 to Worksheet "2" and so on

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list on one Worksheet, which is called "datastore" with about 180 Values. The same excel file has about 180 Sheets with name "1", "2", "3", ... "180".
I want to Copy Value A1 from "datastore" to Table "1" D4, Value A2 from "datastore" to Table "2" D4, A3 from "datastore" to Table "3" D4, and so on.
Value B1 from "datastore" to cell D6 of Table "1" and so on

I tried with a for loop:

```
Sub CopyPasteMacro()
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim iCounterString As String
Dim iCounterStringA As String

For iCounter = 1 To 180
iCounterStringA = "A" + CStr(iCounter)
iCounterString = CStr(iCounter)


Worksheets("datastore").Range(iCounterStringA).Value = 
Worksheets(iCounterString).Range("D4").Value
Next iCounter
End Sub
```

It tells me "Index out of valid Range"

I am a beginner in VBA 
Anyone can help me?

Comment: all the tables are in one excel file. They are called only with numbers... not "Table1", it is "1", "2",...

Comment: Source is one sheet called "datastore". The sources cell A1 should be copied into sheet "1" in D4; A2 of "datastore" into sheet "2" in D4,... Sorry if I expressed myself incomprehensible

Comment: Your assignment should be the other way round I think though  Worksheets(iCounter).Range("D4") = Worksheets("datastore").Range(iCounterStringA) etc. This then means the table part is sort of irrelevant if you are targeting by iCounterString.

Comment: i tried it but it says again "Index out of range".

Comment: On which line? If you step through the code pressing F8 til the error occurs. Then open the locals window and look at the values of each variable....which one is not correct? The assignment swop was not to fix the error simply to make the assignment in the right direction.

Comment: values of the variables are correct it kills the code inside the for-loop on first "run" through the loop

Comment: Are you sure? It sounds like perhaps there isn't a worksheet by the same name as you are looking for potentially. Does it fail on the assignment line?

Comment: Yes i am sure and yes it fails on the assignment line

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct sheet names? Is it possible that one of the sheet contains a blank at the beginning or the end. So for example Sheet `"4"`  is really `"4 " `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your sheets are present.

```
Sub CopyValue()

For i = 1 To 180

Worksheets(CStr(i)).Range("D4").Value = Worksheets("datastore").Range("A" & i).Value

Next

End Sub
```